# Google Geocoder: ZERO_RESULTS when reverse geocoding with result_type like "airport"

Tags: google-geocoding-api

I'm using Google Geocoding API for reverse geocoding (https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/#ReverseGeocoding) and it seems to work unless I pass result_type="airport" or some other type apart from "street_address".

Did anybody experienced this kind of problems?

Comment: I suspect that this probably only works for the US.

Comment: @RamRaider with type "airport" it doesn't work in US too

Comment: Is this issue still happening in the new API?